# How to insert next increment number with a text prefix in when using a command button

Tags: excel, vba

I have a basic userform and need the one textbox to increment the number on the Add/next command, which I get right until you at the "PO" prefix.

I am doing a basic PO entry userform that adds info into the "Entries" sheet. The PO number has a "PO" prefix when clicking the add command I am trying to get the number to increment.

```
Dim currentrow As Long
Dim NextNum As Long
Dim prefix As String
Dim i As Long

Private Sub frmPurchaseOrder_Initialize()
currentrow = 2
End Sub

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
Dim num As Integer
'to check the last filled row
lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Entries").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Entries").Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).value = txtDocNo.Text
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Entries").Cells(lastrow + 1, 2).value = txtLineNumber.Text
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Entries").Cells(lastrow + 1, 3).value = txtDocType.Text

'next one
Me.txtDocType = "PO"
Me.txtLine = Me.txtLine + 1
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
currentrow = 2
Me.txtInvoiceDate = Date
Me.txtDocType = "PO"
Me.txtLine = "1"
Me.txtDocNo = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(Range("DocNoList")) + 1

End Sub
```

The DocNo is in the first column on the entries sheet, range named "DocNoList" 
I would appreciate your help.

Comment: So you mean you need to get the currently max used number in values like: `PO1`, `PO2` ....`PO11` etc..? And this is how you currently tried to retrieve it: `Me.txtDocNo = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(Range("DocNoList")) + 1` ?

Comment: From your question I'm not entirely sure what's not working, but in general I'd recommend using `.Value` to explicitly access the values of userform elements: `Me.txtDocType.Value = "PO"` or `Me.txtLine.Value = Me.txtLine.Value + 1`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the "PO" prefix in front of all the document numbers the `Max` function doesn't work.  It would seem to be easiest to just access the last row of your data and extract the numeric value from that. Replace this line

```
Me.txtDocNo = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(Range("DocNoList")) + 1
```

with

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Entries").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    Me.txtDocNo.Value = Me.txtDocType.Value + CInt(Right(.Value2, Len(.Value2) - 2)) + 1
End With
```

Alternatively:

```
Dim strDocNo As String
strDocNo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Entries").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Value2
Me.txtDocNo.Value = Me.txtDocType.Value + CInt(Right(strDocNo, Len(strDocNo) - 2)) + 1
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you. There is some progress but still not right. I am trying to look for the last number in the list i.e PO125, then add one to get the next number on the list which also includes the PO prefix.
Your first code is working sort of but gives me only 125, but the last number on the list is PO125 and when I initialise the form again it gives a 5. The prefix is not showing. If we need to pull the prefix from somewhere it is in the textbox  "txtDocType"

Comment: I've changed my answer to match what you're describing, please try that again.

Comment: I did some investigating and found the below and patched it in.
Left(Your_variable, 2) & Format(Int(Right(Your_variable, 3)) + 1, "000")

Comment: Hi, I did some investigating and found the below. I have adjusted it and it works. Yay.

= Left(Your_variable, 2) & Format(Int(Right(Your_variable, 3)) + 1, "000")

Thank you for your help

Comment: Beware that this will not work for integers below 100, unless they are zero-padded.